# Return value from overloaded operator Segmentation Fail

Tags: c++, class, return

Got in header

```
DuzaLiczba operator>(const DuzaLiczba& right) const;
string& getData();
virtual ~DuzaLiczba();
private:
string& data;
```

In my class overloaded operators return string in "\002\994\23923\"

```
return DuzaLiczba(wynik);
```

In main

```
        cout << dl3.getData();
        cout.flush();
```

cout.flush throws Segmentation fail.

Return in class is in ascii?
And heres problem. Got any advice?

Comment: What operator returns the sting? can you post the code of getData()? The string "\002\994\23923\" is not a valid string in C++.

Comment: We're also missing the constructor.  My guess is that you're referencing an invalid object.  Make sure the object (string?) you're referencing is still alive or use a reference counted pointer.  Seems similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199067/c-catching-dangling-reference

Comment: And by any chance is `cout.flush();` the last line of a function? If so, I'm guessing `~DuzaLiczba` is to blame.

Answer (score 1):

You should not hold a reference in your class. You held a reference to a local variable, which was destructed and then accessed causing the segmentation fault. Also, operator> and operator< return bool normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DuzaLiczba {
public:
    DuzaLiczba(string& input);
    DuzaLiczba(const DuzaLiczba& orig);
    bool operator==(const DuzaLiczba &other) const;
    bool operator!=(const DuzaLiczba &other) const;
    DuzaLiczba operator+(const DuzaLiczba& right) const;
    DuzaLiczba operator-(const DuzaLiczba& right) const;
     DuzaLiczba operator<(const DuzaLiczba& right) const;
    DuzaLiczba operator>(const DuzaLiczba& right) const;
    string& getData();
    virtual ~DuzaLiczba();
private:
    string& data;

};
```

And == operator

```
bool DuzaLiczba::operator==(const DuzaLiczba &other) const {
string liczba1 = this->data;
string liczba2 = right.data;
char index1 = liczba1.length();
char index2 = liczba2.length();
short k;
short o;
short f = 0; //przeniesienie
string wynik;
int sizefi = 0;
char temp;
int i = 0;
//"gupie" to C# RUUUULEEEZ
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXoc9hOIj3M hahahaa "D

if (liczba1.length() == liczba2.length()) { //najpierw dlugosc szybciej niz pokolei
    for (i = 0; i < index1; i++) { 
        if (liczba1[i] == liczba2[i]) {   //sprawdza kazdy element jesli sie rozni to false
            wynik =
                    "TRUE";

        } else {
            wynik = "FALSE";
        }

    }

} else {
    wynik = "FALSE";
}

return DuzaLiczba(wynik);

 }
```

And retturn data

```
string& DuzaLiczba::getData() {
 return data; //zwoloniony string
     }
```

All i want to return a string.
dl1 = "123089127312890372109371203971293012903"
dl2 = "12837129037812903812903"
eg. DuzaLiczba dl3(dl1+dl2)
and cout it.

Code inside class do math great.

Or create overloader operator "<<".

Comment: You should edit your question and add this code.  This is not an answer to your question.

Comment: If you want to add to or modify your question you should use the "edit" button. Answers are reserved for, well, answers.